# Manage exception on db login instead of showing stacktrace

Tags: php

How do you manage exception, I mean *do something* when exception occurs instead of printing the stacktrace.

```
 try{
            $this->koneksi = new PDO($this->info,$this->user,$this->pass);
       $this->koneksi->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        }catch(SQLException $e){


            // instead of executing the following, it just print the stacktrace
            echo "error on login";
        }
```

I try also something like

```
function check(){

$this->koneksi = new PDO($this->info,$this->user,$this->pass);
  if ( $this->koneksi){
            return true;

          }

     else {
        return false;
        }
  }
```

so
if the check function returns false do something, but still just printing the stacktrace.

Comment: you never catch the exception in your "something like" code, so it's free to bubble back up the call chain.

Comment: @MarcB, please explain more to blind ppl like me.

Comment: If you catch only the SQLException than a lot of other Exceptions can trigger the "stacktrace". catch Exception insted.

Comment: how do i do that? sorry i'm still beginner